# Replacing Characters in String: first one character replaces with string then another character with another string

Tags: python, python-3.x

If i start with a string called `x` for `N=0` , that is

```
x="G"
```

Then if I have a range `N` , that is 1 , I want to replace `G` from x with `SRGRS`, so that

```
x1="SRGRS"
```

Then if N=2, I want to replace `S` in `x1` with `GLSLG` and `G` with `SRGRS`, so that I get

```
x2="GLSLGRSRGRSRGLSLG"
```

and then continue with N+=1, I'm replacing "G" and "S" from x2 with the corresponding string..

how do I write a loop, that does this continuously?

I've tried to use `str.replace()` , but I can't it to work :(

edit:
in the loop:
If there is "G"in the string, it should be replaced with "SRGRS"
If there is "S" in the string, it should be replaced with "GLSLG"

Comment: so you mean to replace each `G` with `SRGRS` and each `S` with `GLSLG` on each loop?

Comment: How do you determine what you want to replace for each loop?

Answer (score 1):

For `nbIter` iterations, replaces simultaneously "S" by "GLSLG" and "G" by "SRGRS".

```
nbIter=4
x="G"
print(x)

for i in range(nbIter):
    newX=""
    for char in x:
        if char=="S":
            newX+="GLSLG"
        elif char=="G":
            newX+="SRGRS"
        else:
            newX+=char
    x=newX
    print(x)
```

Comment: it is possible to use a while loop? i only want to print the latest string and stop if i>N

Comment: Isn't your N the same thing as my nbIter ?

Comment: you can always replace a `for` by a `while`, just try it yourself